# Apache Flume spoolDirectory configuration is failing

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I am using the following code to write the files in my source directory to hdfs.

```
  # Initialize agent's source, channel and sink
agent.sources = test
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = flumeHDFS

# Setting the source to spool directory where the file exists
agent.sources.test.type = spooldir
agent.sources.test.spoolDir = /Data

# Setting the channel to memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
# Max number of events stored in the memory channel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
# agent.channels.memoryChannel.batchSize = 15000
agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactioncapacity = 1000000

# Setting the sink to HDFS
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.path = /user/team
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Write format can be text or writable
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

# use a single csv file at a time
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 1

# rollover file based on maximum size of 10 MB
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount=0
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=2000
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.batchSize =1000000

# never rollover based on the number of events
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0

# rollover file based on max time of 1 min
#agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
# agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.idleTimeout = 600

# Connect source and sink with channel
agent.sources.TwitterExampleDir.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.channel = memoryChannel
```

But I am getting the following error

> : Failed to configure component!
>   org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: Failed to configure
>   component!
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.source.SourceConfiguration.configure(SourceConfigurati
>   on.java:110)
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSources(
>   FlumeConfiguration.java:566)
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeCon
>   figuration.java:345)
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.access$000(Flume
>   Configuration.java:212)
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfigur
>   ation.java:126)
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.(FlumeConfiguration.java:108)
>           at org.apache.flume.node.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.getFlumeConfigurat
>   ion(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:193)
>           at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(Abstrac
>   tConfigurationProvider.java:94)
>           at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcher
>   Runnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$
>   301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Sch
>   eduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:11
>   42)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:6
>   17)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: No channels set for test
>           at org.apache.flume.conf.source.SourceConfiguration.configure(SourceConfigurati
>   on.java:68)
>           ... 15 more

Can anyone help what should I do to put my data from the source directory /Data to hdfs directory /user/team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stack Trace mention:**

```
No channels set for test
```

You have a specified `sources` as `test`

```
agent.sources = test
```

But while connecting it to `channel`

```
agent.sources.TwitterExampleDir.channels = memoryChannel
```

so you have to mention `test` instead of `TwitterExampleDir`